# Failed to execute goal on project swagger-java-client: Compilation failure

Tags: java, maven, compiler-errors, swagger-codegen

Context: I'm trying to build a swagger-codegen-cli generated package to generate a jar as a dependency for a maven spring boot java project

Getting this error message when running `mvn clean install`:

```
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] COMPILATION ERROR :
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] <path-to-project>/Projects/dev/Sellers_JavaCL/src/main/java/io/swagger/client/model/BatchRequest.java:[33,21] package javax.annotationmvn does not exist
[INFO] 1 error
[INFO] -------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  3.041 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2024-02-18T18:07:32-08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) on project swagger-java-client: Compilation failure
[ERROR] <path-to-project>/Projects/dev/Sellers_JavaCL/src/main/java/io/swagger/client/model/BatchRequest.java:[33,21] package javax.annotationmvn does not exist
```

I looked into the `BatchRequest.java` class and found this where annotationmvn is red in intellij because it can't be found:

```
@ApiModel(description = "Common properties of batch requests against individual APIs.")
@javax.annotationmvn.Generated(value = "io.swagger.codegen.languages.JavaClientCodegen", date = "2024-02-17T14:18:13.581-08:00")
```

This swagger java client package seems to be compiling in Java 1.7 my spring boot project is building in Java 17. I tried to download the old 1.7 jdk to build and compile this project but it just throws the same error.

Things I tried

- Deleted my `.m2` folder and rerun `mvn clean install`
- Tried to change the JDK to 17, 11, 1.8, 1.7
- Tried to resolve dependencies using `mvn dependency:tree`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not found becouse doesn't exist @javax.annotation**mvn**.Generated

@javax.annotation.Generated is correct :)

Comment: I am so embarrassed that I wasted precious storage bytes in SO's backend for this question. The problem was I accidentally added the "mvn" part.... reverting back to @javax.annotation.Generated is correct